# How to get and build all dependencies of go package which has no main function?

Tags: go

I have a following project:

```
myrepo/     # root package, no main() function
  |-common/ # common utilties package
  |-cmd/    # CLI root
  |   |-myrepo-a/   # CLI application A
  |   |   |-main.go # CLI application A main package/function, 
  |   |             # setting up feature A for CLI use
  |   |-myrepo-b/   # CLI application B
  |       |-main.go # CLI application B main package/function,
  |                 # setting up feature B for CLI use
  |-aspecific/  # package with generic implementation for feature A
  |-bspecific/  # package with generic implementation for feature B
  |-generate.go # file dispatching //go:generate instructions
```

How to get and build dependencies of such myrepo project?

`go get -v ./...` invocation yields errors:

```
runtime.main_main·f: relocation target main.main not defined
runtime.main_main·f: undefined: "main.main"
```

Can i avoid manually specifying each of subpackages for such invocation as in `go get ./common/... ./cmd/... ./aspecific/... ./bspecific/...`, as such hard-coding might result in desync between actual project state and packages getting built?

Comment: Couldn't add `go-get` tag. If somebody with >1500 reputation could do that, might be helpful, as we already got `go-build` one.

Comment: You cannot build a main package without a main function. Why don't you have one? What would be the point of such a package?

Comment: `go get` works for all packages and it loads all dependecies by default. If you use the package in your program and you build your program everything should work then.

Comment: Did you run `go get -v ./...` and that's a typo in the question, or did you actually run `go get v ./...`? The latter might yield an error, the former should work. You don't need a `main` function to run `go get` to get your dependencies.

Comment: @Peter I don't want to build package without main function, I want to get & build it's dependencies. @apxp i have a package "myrepo" in `generate.go`, but thats an error for `go get`. @Adrian it was a typo. And no, `go get -v ./...` does not work work without a hitch: it prints error messages and returns error code 2 instead of successful 0 exit code.

Comment: What errors does it print? Because the errors you quoted in the question shouldn't be generated by `get`, only by `build`. Note that you can get your dependencies without building a main package, you can't build them - building would be meaningless in that case, but getting them should be sufficient to e.g. get autocomplete in your editor to work.

Comment: @Adrian Those errors are after jut go get invocation, it builds and installs fetched packages into $GOPATH/bin by default, unless -d is specified. And it would not be meaningless before go generate, because they may be providing binaries required for //go:generate annotations

Comment: That would require building those specific packages, and would imply a more complex build process which should be documented.